# Configure phone auth for second firebase project in react native app

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I'm struggling to configure two Firebase projects in one React Native app. I've successfully initialized the second app by following the instructions at [Firebase Docs](https://rnfirebase.io/app/usage#secondary-apps). But, when I use the secondary phone auth, it fails.

This is the error message on Android:

> This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ A safety_net_token was passed, but no matching SHA-256 was registered in the Firebase console. Please make sure that this application’s packageName/SHA256 pair is registered in the Firebase Console. ]

And this is the error message on iOS:

> [Error: [auth/invalid-app-credential] Invalid token.]

In the Firebase Console of the second app, I've set up all credentials to identify clients:

- iOS: p8 file to the Cloud Messaging tab, add URL schemes, ...
- Android: SHA-1, and SHA-256 fingerprints

Is this implementation possible? Am I missing any step?

P/s: I also have created a new discussion in the rnfirebase Github repository: [Link](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/discussions/6463)

Answer (score 0):

It happens in case when App **Bundle identifier** (**Xcode** -> **General**) doesn't match with firebase App Bundle ID.
One React Native can have different schemes but Firebase Phone Auth requires different Bundle IDs.